# Django - Getting matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django

my template has three columns in one form where they work separately. If I give input for contact column and male column it will save in my database.
So basically I want to update the male only as contacts,male and from are present in same html form.
I can update the contact but not the male or female inputs.
They all are in same page.I want to make working differently so I can update them.

```
from django.urls import path , include
from  . import views



urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
      path('info/', views.info, name='info'),
        path('features/', views.features, name='features'),
          path('add/', views.add, name='add'),
            path('add/' ,views.success, name='success'),
              path('update/<str:pk_test>/' ,views.update, name='update')
   

]
```

views.py

````
def update(request,pk_test):
    template_name = 'update.html' 
    contact = Contact.objects.all()  
    # c_form = commentForm(instance=contacts)
    # if request.method =='POST':
    #     c_form = commentForm(request.POST,instance=contacts)
    #     if c_form.is_valid() :
             
    #         contact = c_form.save()     
    #         messages.success(request, "Contact Updated")
    #         return redirect("success")     
    #     else:     
    #         c_form = commentForm()            
    # context = {
      
    #     'c_form' : c_form,
       

    # }
    
   
    
    contacts=  Male.objects.get(id=pk_test)
    male_f = maleForm(instance=contacts)

     
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        contact_m.save()
        c_form = commentForm(request.POST)
        male_f = maleForm(request.POST,instance=contacts)
        if male_f.is_valid():
            contact_m = male_f.save(commit=False)
            contact_m.contact1 = contact
            contact_m.save()
            messages.success(request, "Contact Updated")
            return redirect("success")    
        else:
            male_f = maleForm()


    context = {

        'male_f' : male_f
    }



    
    return render(request , template_name , context)```
````

models.py

```
class Male(models.Model):
    contact1 = models.ForeignKey(Contact,  on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    chest = models.CharField(max_length=30 , blank=True)
    neck = models.CharField(max_length=30 , blank=True)
    full_shoulder_width = models.CharField(max_length=30 , blank=True)
    right_sleeve = models.CharField(max_length=30 , blank=True)
    left_sleeve = models.CharField(max_length=30 , blank=True)
    bicep = models.CharField(max_length=30 , blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return chest
```

add.py

```
def add(request):
    template_name = 'add.html'
    c_form = commentForm()
    m_form = maleForm()   
    f_form = femaleForm()
                    

   
    contact = Contact.objects.all()  
    if request.method =='POST':
        c_form = commentForm(request.POST)
        m_form = maleForm(request.POST)
        f_form = femaleForm(request.POST)
        if c_form.is_valid() and (m_form.is_valid() or f_form.is_valid()):
                gender = c_form.cleaned_data.get('gender')
                username= c_form.cleaned_data.get('name')
                contact = c_form.save()     
                
                if gender == 'female':
                       
                        female = f_form.save(commit=False)
                        female.contact2 = contact
                        female.save()
                        messages.success(request, f"Form Submitted: {username}")
                        return redirect("success")
                else:
                        male = m_form.save(commit=False)
                        male.contact1 = contact
                        male.save()
                       
                        messages.success(request, f"Form Submitted: {username}")
                        return redirect("success")     
        else:     
                    c_form = commentForm()
                    m_form = maleForm()
```

Comment: `contacts=  Male.objects.get()` this means that if there is no `Male`, or multiple `Male`s, it will raise an error.

Comment: can you check again ? I forgot to add contacts=  Male.objects.get(id=pk_test) still getting error.Though I ave only one male class.

Comment: <int:pk_test> should be right

Comment: i tried but didn't work